# Runtime.getRuntime().exec on host from inside a Docker process

Tags: java, docker

I have a Java program that runs inside a Docker container. This program needs to execute a shell command that should be run by the host system, but just calling `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(...)` executes it inside the Docker container (as it should be).

Is there a way I can start a process from inside a container so the process runs outside? I suspect that the exec command should go via Docker to tell it that the command itself needs to be run on the host, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I am not sure if this is possible. The point of docker is to isolate services from eachother; the docker pod should have no context of its super, outside of the resources explicitly passed to it ( i could be wrong ).

Comment: I agree with Matt,  in fact any process that runs inside container actually runs on host machine with different uid.  I bet you can achieve your objective by exposing port in container and mapping it on the host.

Comment: If you explain us what for you want to do this, we will try to help you to find out another way.

Comment: I'm trying to execute a python script from my java application using Py4J. In order for me to do that, I need to start the python executor script as a separate process, but it runs in the same container as its parent process and, therefore, can't find python and its packages.

You are all correct. I think I should, instead, containerize the python side of Py4J and have it running as a separate container. The two containers should still be able to talk to each other, since that's done via TCP.

Comment: If you link 2 container on the same machine,  they will talk to each other using Unix sockets. You should use docker-compose to build you application.

Comment: using side car container. see here https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwichKfqx4vYAhWK1RQKHYAcC9AQFgg1MAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.voxxed.com%2F2015%2F01%2Fuse-container-sidecar-microservices%2F&usg=AOvVaw0B2Dj4Z9YHMQWojmjBECGS

Answer (score 0):

The idea how to do it can be based on how docker comand line client communicates with docker service. It is just a client, that uses unix socket (i.e. just file) to stream commands to the service. Thus you may connect 1) the service on the host machine via tcp (google for docker TCP socket) 2) may make volumes of docker host machine with docker utility to make them availdable on the docker container like those parameters of docker run on Ubuntu

-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker -v /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so.7

that make you possible to exectude docker utility in container and actually all commands will be done in host service